# how to call .js after page is loaded

Tags: c#

i need to call customFormElements.js js function after aspx page is loaded, after submit button is clicked. can i do this and if yes how?

window.onload option is not good...

i need to call this file after i press submit button becouse aspx ajax library clear my js file logic and i need to reload it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what i am getting is that you want to call a javascript function after your page is loaded for this i think its better to use setTimeout function:

With JavaScript, it is possible to execute some code after a specified time-interval. This is called timing events.

It's very easy to time events in JavaScript. The two key methods that are used are:

```
* setTimeout() - executes a code some time in the future
* clearTimeout() - cancels the setTimeout()
```

Note: The setTimeout() and clearTimeout() are both methods of the HTML DOM Window object.
The setTimeout() Method
Syntax
var t=setTimeout("javascript statement",milliseconds);

The setTimeout() method returns a value - In the statement above, the value is stored in a variable called t. If you want to cancel this setTimeout(), you can refer to it using the variable name.

The first parameter of setTimeout() is a string that contains a JavaScript statement. This statement could be a statement like "alert('5 seconds!')" or a call to a function, like "alertMsg()".

The second parameter indicates how many milliseconds from now you want to execute the first parameter.

**so just create a javascript function in which use setTimeout to call your desired javascript funciton as set time seconds for that**

and u can then call this javascript function on

```
protected void Page_LoadComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//call javascript function which contains setTimeout();
}
```

you can see good example on below link:

http://dotnetacademy.blogspot.com/2010/09/timer-in-javascript.html

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

Answer (score 1):

Did you find any problem in using both **OnClientClick** and **OnClick** events of **Button** control?. In this case both the handlers will be executed after you click the button. The client Handler(Javascript function) will be executed first then the OnClick server side handler will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Bind a `submit` event handler to the form so that it executes when the form is submitted. The function will fire before the form is submitted. (Thank you to Stan Rogers)

Comment: i need to call JS function/file after some submit button is clicked

Comment: I don't think you can call a javascript function after a form is submitted. I fail to see the reason for that anyway.

Comment: Dude -- when you bind the call to the onsubmit event of the form, it runs after the submit button is physically clicked but before the actual submission occurs (that is, before the click event is sent anywhere). If you return false to the event, you prevent the submission.

Comment: I suppose I should have used the full "CyberDude" rather than the more familiar form of address -- my remark was meant for someone else's edification.

Comment: @CyberDude; You call the function before it is submitted.

Comment: @Stan Rogers; My bad. You are right, `return false;` is not needed.

Comment: I didn't say "after the button is clicked" but "after the form is submitted".

Comment: @CyberDude `I don't think you can call a javascript function after a form is submitted.` - That's because you don't. You attach a submit event handler which is executed BEFORE the form is submitted.

Comment: I know all that, no need to twist the English language in all directions. Apparently our friend in need here either didn't know that or didn't express himself/herself clear enough in his/her turn.

Comment: @CyberDude: so then, what is the source of your confusion?